# Will App-Status "Pending Developer Release" stop Beta-Testing in Testflight

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, review

Is it possible to have an App reviewed by Apple and keep on Beta-Testing?

In the iTunes Connect Developer Guide it says: "When the app becomes "Ready for Sale" in the App Store, testing automatically stops on earlier builds, and you will be unable to view or test them."

But  what happens If we would  choose "Manual release" while submitting an App for App Store Review so the App-status after successful review will be "Pending Developer Release".

1) Is it correct that the status "Pending Developer Release" won't stop testing automatically and our Beta-Tester still can test with Testflight?

2) Is it correct, that if we press "Release now" while the app status is "Pending Developer Release" it changes to "Ready for Sale" and Beta-Testing will stop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I talk about Testflight Internal Testers.

> 1) Is it correct that the status "Pending Developer Release" won't stop testing automatically and our Beta-Tester still can test with Testflight?

It is correct. Your Beta-Tester still can test in "Pending Developer Release".

> 2) Is it correct, that if we press "Release now" while the app status is "Pending Developer Release" it changes to "Ready for Sale" and Beta-Testing will stop?

It is correct. If you press "Release now", the app status of Testflight changes to "UNAVAILABLE".

example:
[image]

**UPDATE(9/27):**

> Is it the same with external Testers?

YES! I have tried that.

> Can external testers keep on testing after the App received the Status "Pending Developer Release".

The status of my app is "Pending Developer Release".

[image]

External testers can keep on testing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer and your example.  That's good news for us. 

You "Talk about Testflight Internal Testers". Our main focus is on external testers. Is it the same with external Testers?
Can external testers keep on testing after the App received the Status "Pending Developer Release".
We hope so

Thx in advance

Comment: Apple just confirmed that it is exactly like Kosuke said even for external Testers.